# called object is not a function or function pointer

Tags: c

I am writing a program for a low-pass filter. When I compile I get the following error:

> called object is not a function or function pointer

for the variables I declared with double. Any idea why this is happening?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  double omega1, omega2, omegac, T, dt;
  int N, method;
  FILE *in;

  // Open the file and scan the input variables.
  if (argv[1] == NULL) {
    printf("You need an input file.\n");
    return -1;
  }
  in = fopen(argv[1], "r");
  if (in == NULL)
    return -1;
  fscanf(in, "%lf", &omega1);
  fscanf(in, "%lf", &omega2);
  fscanf(in, "%lf", &omegac);
  fscanf(in, "%d", &method);

  T = 3 * 2 * M_PI / omega1; // Total time
  N = 20 * T / (2 * M_PI / omega2); // Total number of time steps
  dt = T / N;   // Time step ("delta t")

  // Method number 1 corresponds to the finite difference method.
  if (method == 1) {
    int i;
    double Voutnew = 0, Voutcur = 0, Voutprev = 0;

    for (i = N; i != 0; i--) {
      Voutnew = ((1/((1/((sqrt(2))(dt)(omegac))) + (1/((dt)(dt)(omegac) (omegac))))) * (((2/((dt)(dt)(omegac)(omegac))) - 1)(Voutcur) + (1/((1/((sqrt(2))(dt)(omegac))) - (1/((dt)(dt)(omegac)(omegac)))))(Voutprev) + Sin((omega1)(T)) + (1/2)(Sin((omega2)(T)))));
      Voutcur = Voutnew; // updates variable
      Voutprev = Voutcur;   // passes down variable to next state
      printf("%lf\n", Voutnew);
    }
  } else {
    // Print error message.
    printf("Incorrect method number.\n");
    return -1;
  }
  fclose(in);
  return 0;
}
```

Here is the list of errors I get:

```
In function 'main':
Line 38: error: called object '1.41421356237309514547462185873882845044136047363e+0' is not a function
Line 38: error: called object 'dt' is not a function
Line 38: error: called object 'dt' is not a function
Line 38: error: called object '1.41421356237309514547462185873882845044136047363e+0' is not a function
Line 38: error: called object 'dt' is not a function
Line 38: error: called object 'omega1' is not a function
Line 38: error: called object 'omega2' is not a function
Line 38: error: called object '0' is not a function
```

Comment: don't check this `if (argv[1] == NULL)` check `argc`.

Comment: Multiplication requires the `*` operator, e.g. `x = y * z`. The expression `x = (y)(z)` is not valid C.

Comment: did not know that. That fixed everything except now I have undefined references to Sin. I am probably calling the funciton incorrectly. Will have to check my syntax

Comment: Write `sin` instead of `Sin`. C is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

You need the multiplication operator

```
((sqrt(2))(dt)(omegac)
```

for example, is wrong, you should specify the multiplication operator explicitly in all programming languages I know at least

```
sqrt(2) * dt * omegac
```

also, using too many parentheses makes your code really hard to read, so don't.

The use of parentheses was the case for the error message, since

```
(dt)(omegac)
```

is interpreted as if `dt` was a function and `omegac` a parameter passed to it, and since `dt` is not a function, the error message makes sense.

This is just a small part of the code that needs to be fixed, and if I were you, I would split the expression in subexpressions, it's not really easy to see a mistake in the large one you have there.

Undefined references to `Sin` are because c is case sensitive, there is no function called `Sin`, it's `sin`.

Comment: After making the suggested edits, I am no longer getting any compiler warnings. However I am always getting zero returned when I link it to an input that should send it through the loop quite a few times

Comment: You need to use floating point values for the calculations to be correct `1/2` is evaluated as an integer to `0`. Do it like this `1.0 / 2.0` and change all the `1`'s too, and it will work, provided that the expression is correct.