# object is not a function or function pointer

Tags: c

I am getting the following compilation error:

> prog.c:13:5: error: called object is not a function or function pointer
>     a=250(n-1)+192;

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    long long n,a;
    int t;

    scanf("%d",&t);
    while(t--){
        scanf("%lld",&n);
        a=250(n-1)+192;
        printf("%lld\n",a);
    }
}
```

Comment: `250(n-1)` Is trying to  call a number, which is neither a function nor an object. What is your question? If your background is more math than programming, then try a `*`in between.

Comment: Thank you.Putting a* worked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [called object is not a function or function pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28663599/called-object-is-not-a-function-or-function-pointer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C, you always have to write a `*` character for multiplication, as this:

```
a=250*(n-1)+192;
```

Comment: Yes your answer helped me.

Answer (score 0):

You can't put a numeric constant right next to parenthesis like that.  This does not denote multiplication but a function call with `250` as the name of the function.

Use the binary `*` operator for multiplication.

```
a=250*(n-1)+192;
```